# Should I use sqlite3_finalize after i performed a query with sqlite3_exec?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I'm using Sqlite3 in my iPhone app, I was getting some unwanted rollbacks apparently in a random basis, However I don't know if this has something to do with the fact that I don't finalize the statements with `sqlite3_finalize`, since as far as I know `sqlite3_exec` takes care of it.

Also I found some SELECTs with `sqlite3_prepare_v2` that I didn't finalize, so I know I must finalize these, however should I do the same with the ones in `sqlite3_exec`?

One example of my statements is:

```
NSString *query=@"UPDATE books SET title='newName' WHERE id='21';";
if ((result=sqlite3_open([database UTF8String], &_database))==SQLITE_OK) {
    result=sqlite3_exec(_database, [query UTF8String],NULL,NULL,&errorMsg);
    if (result!=SQLITE_OK) {
        printf("\n%s",errorMsg);
        sqlite3_free(errorMsg);
    }
    sqlite3_close(_database);
}
```

Should I `sqlite3_finalize(result)` before closing the database?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. You don't need ,because `sqlite3_finalize()` function is called to delete a **prepared statement** which is created by using `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` or a related function.

Answer (score 1):

No need to call sqlite3_finalize() when working with sqlite3_exec.
This is because sqlite3_exec is a shortcut for 3 functions:

1. sqlite3_prepare_v2()
2. sqlite3_step()
3. sqlite3_finalize()

You can also read about this in a small sqlite tutorial at:
http://www.iosdevelopment.be/sqlite-tutorial/